# Count number of tables and it's columns in access database using query

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can I get the count of tables and it's columns in access database using query?

Answer (score 1):

There is a system table called "MSysObjects" that holds details about all of the objects in the current database. You can use this, together with a short VBA function, to get the information that you need.

Firstly, paste this VBA code into a module:

```
Function fCountColumn(strTable) As String
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    fCountColumn = DBEngine(0)(0).TableDefs(strTable).Fields.Count
fExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "fCountColumn", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume fExit
End Function
```

Next, create a query, and set the SQL to be:

```
SELECT [Name], fCountColumn([Name]) AS ColumnCount
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE [Type]=1 AND [Flags]=0
ORDER BY [Name] ASC;
```

This returns just native Access tables - for other  tables you will need to add to the Flags and Type that are being queried.

An alternative, non-SQL way, would be to loop the TableDefs collection in VBA, and again use the `.Fields.Count` property of each TableDef.

Regards,